# Tiff will not update georeferencing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, georeferencing, geotiff-tiff, update

I am having a problem georeferencing. I have a photograph (.tif) that will not save georeferencing. When the .tif raster appears on the table of contents, there is a ":0" added to the end of the naming convention. I then fit to display and start adding control points. I can create a text from link table, and rectify file no problem. The problem arises when I go to update georeferencing. The image will disappear along with the control points. When I search for the raster, I find it @ 0,0. Any ideas?

I found a similar post from a few years back. Same problem but his solution didn't help my issue...

Comment: I would first make a copy of the Tif, Conversion Tools, Raster to Other Format, choose Tif.

Comment: Well that took care of the ":0" that was added to the naming convention when the .tif is added to the map. The .tif also builds pyramids now, so that is a plus. The georeferencing is still not sticking. It seems that the control points are just not "talking" to the raster...

Comment: After you georeference the tif, you should Rectify to apply the transformation. This will write out another geotiff. You can then define the Spatial Reference also.

Comment: Can you add a tag for the software you are working with?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a work around that I figured out. For some reason it seems like arc does not like to save the control points or build pyramids for raster over 100MB. The image I was trying to georef were 103MB .tif files.
The solution, I cropped it down in Ps and it would georef just fine. Definitely a software issue.